# Add hover text over a small image

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table whose last column allows a delete of that row. It includes an image (of an X), that column looks like this.

```
<td id="delete:$row[recordID]"> 
    <a href="#" class="delete cent" >
    <img alt="x" border="0" src="images/delete.png" />
    </a>
</td>
```

I would like for the image to enlarge when hovered over and I would like to add some text when the mouse hovers over the image. The text should say "Click to Delete", I tried using jQuery like below to do this but nothing every happens. No text is displayed and the image does not grow regardless of how long I let the mouse hover over the 'x' image. I'm not sure how to add the text to his idea. How do I get this to work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a.delete').on('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).css( {
        'height':'175px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because `this` in your case is the `a` tag and not the image. So you are changing the height of this tag and not the image. Instead you can use `find()` function in order to select the image inside the tag like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.delete').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('img').css({
      'height': '175px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="delete:$row[recordID]">
  <a href="#" class="delete cent">
    <img alt="x" border="0" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  </a>
</td>
```

This is still not enough as you have also to implement the `mouseleave` event to put the image back to its normal size.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.delete').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('img').css({
      'height': '175px'
    });
  });
  $('a.delete').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('img').css({
      'height': 'auto'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="delete:$row[recordID]">
  <a href="#" class="delete cent">
    <img alt="x" border="0" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  </a>
</td>
```

---

By the way I suggest you to go with a CSS solution which is easier to implement. You may use the hover effect on CSS and pseudo element to add the text you need.

You may try something like this (adjust the CSS of text and image as you need)  :

```css
a.delete {
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:visible;
}

a.delete img {
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s
}


a.delete:hover img {
  height: 100px;
}

a.delete:hover::after {
  content:"Click Here to delete";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  left:100%;
  top:40%;
  font-size:14px;
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="delete:$row[recordID]">
  <a href="#" class="delete cent">
    <img alt="x" border="0" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: This is a great answer @Termani Afif especially showing me how to use the CSS instead of the javascript. I found it worked best without any text however. With text the cell the image is in starts to jump all around. When I removed the text from the CSS the image nicely grows and shrinks just as it should. Do you know of a way to make the text appear to the right of the image, maybe outside the cell? If not I'll use the solution without the text and mark your answer as my solution.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser yes of course you can make the image appear where you want ;) you can for example remove `display:block` and it will appear next to image. I can you show a small screenshot of how you want exactly the text i can provide you with the exact CSS ;)

Comment: @KeithDKaiser i improved the CSS solution by making the text outside the flow (using absolute position) to avoid the "jump" effect

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you!